# Nesting a second $.getJSON request with the WordPress REST API to retrieve category names/links

Tags: javascript

I am working with the WordPress REST API to retrieve blog posts and this is all working nicely. I have an initial `$.getJSON` call to retrieve the relevant posts, I then `$.each` over the data to return the relevant blobs of HTML to render to the page.

However, I am a bit stuck with how to implement the list of categories for each post. The posts endpoint only lists the category ID, so I need to somehow query the category endpoint, passing in the ID, to construct the category links. 
Can I nest a `$.getJSON` call within the `$.each` to query the category for that post? Struggling with how to construct this.

This is what I have so far (just extracted snippets of the relevant code):

```
var state = {
    totalPages: null,
    posts: [],
    page: 1
}

getPostsByCategoryId: function getPostsByCategoryId(id, container) {

    $.getJSON('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]='+id+'&filter[orderby]=title&filter[order]=ASC&filter[posts_per_page]=4&page='+state.page+'', function(data, status, xhr) {

        state.totalPages = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-WP-TotalPages');

        $.each(data, function() {
            var featuredImage = null;

            var cats = this.categories;
            var categories = [];

            // // Loop over the categories
            $.each(cats, function() {
                $.getJSON('/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/13', function(data) {
                    var categoryItem = '<a class="category" href="' + data.link + '">' + data.name + '</a>';
                    categories.push(categoryItem);
                });
            });



            var post = $('<div class="news"><div class="detail"><p class="postmeta"><a class="category" href="#">CATEGORIES</a></p><h3 class="title"><a href="' + this.link + '">' + this.title.rendered + '</a></h3><a href="' + this.link + '">View article</a></div></div>');

            state.posts.push(post);
        });

        container.append(state.posts);

        if (state.page == state.totalPages)
            $('#loadmore').addClass('disabled');

        state.page++;

    });
    return false;
}
```

Thank you :)

UPDATED CODE - cannot read property rendered of undefined

```
getPostsByCategoryId: function getPostsByCategoryId(id, container) {

$.getJSON('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]='+id+'&filter[orderby]=title&filter[order]=ASC&filter[posts_per_page]=4&page='+state.page+'', function(data, status, xhr) {

    state.totalPages = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-WP-TotalPages');

    $.each(data, function() {
        var featuredImage = null;

        var cats = this.categories;
        var categories = [];
        var requests = [];

        // // Loop over the categories
        $.each(cats, function() {
            var xhr = $.getJSON('/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/13', function(data) {
                var categoryItem = '<a class="category" href="' + data.link + '">' + data.name + '</a>';
                categories.push(categoryItem);
            });
            requests.push(xhr);
        });

        $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {

            var post = $('<div class="news"><div class="detail"><p class="postmeta"><a class="category" href="#">CATEGORIES</a></p><h3 class="title"><a href="' + this.link + '">' + this.title.rendered + '</a></h3><a href="' + this.link + '">View article</a></div></div>');

            state.posts.push(post);
        });

    });


    container.append(state.posts);
    blogPostLoader.toggleLoadingIcon($('.loading i'));

    if (state.page == state.totalPages)
        $('#loadmore').addClass('disabled');

    state.page++;

});
return false;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that `$.getJSON` is *still* asynchronous, you can't push to an outside array and expect the values to be there *now*, when the ajax request will finish *later*.

Comment: I thought so, is there a way to chain a success function to populate the array?

Comment: Something like this maybe ? -> https://jsfiddle.net/cj4dad9a/

Comment: Works perfectly thanks so much, but how can I inject the categories (which I have access to into the $.when statement) into the `post` output below (where I create the fill block of HTML to render to the page?

Comment: You have to put that code inside `$.when` as well, and wait for the data, and then append the posts to the page.

Comment: Thanks adeneo, I think I might have done this incorrectly, pasted the code I updated above. Am getting the error: cannot read property rendered of undefined

Comment: I can access the categories, from within the $.when, but I am really struggling to workout how to access the post information from the initial ajax request, and build up the HTML with the post information and category list combined :(

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done within pure jQuery. You need to write custom endpoint for your REST API. At this endpoint you will return categories of each post. It's pretty big job, there is official WP tutorial how to add custom endpoint to API:

http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

I think this can help, please let me know if you need more help.